# Scala Syntax: Syntactic sugar for converting a Function0 into function1?

Tags: scala

Sorry for the nebulous title, I had a hard time to to formulate what I mean. For that reason, lets directly dive into the code:

```
def bar(b: Int => String) = b(23)
def foo(b: => String) = bar(_ => b)
foo("foo" + "bar")
```

I found a similar code in the play framework and was wondering what actually happens with that code. I tinkered a bit and figured that `bar(_ => b)` will just create a function1 with the required argument type (given by `bar`s signature) and uses the given function0 to generate the return value, ignoring the actual parameter of the function1.

However, this is just me trying to figure out what happens, a more definitive answer would be way better for my understanding - and besides that I might be completely wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Basically, "Am i right?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sort of right, except that `=> String` is not a Function0 - `() => String` is.

`=> String` is a call-by-name string. It'll be evaluated when it's referred to.

`def foo(b: String) = bar(_ => b)` would also get the job done, with the exception that `b` would be evaluated eagerly.